# xampp - Do I need to change php.ini and sendmail.ini to send emails with phpMailer?

Tags: php, xampp, smtp, localhost, phpmailer

When I click on submit button

```
if (isset($_POST['btn_signup'])) {...
```

It should send an email to the registered user

```
require './PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';             // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                     // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'myEmail@gmail.com'; // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'myPassword';            // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                          // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->setFrom('myEmail@gmail.com', 'Admin');
    $mail->addAddress($_POST['email']);   // Add a recipient
    //$mail->addReplyTo('info@phpmailer.com', 'phpmailer');
    //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    $mail->isHTML(true);  // Set email format to HTML

    $bodyContent = '<h1>How to Send Email using PHP in Localhost</h1>';
    $bodyContent .= '<p>This is the HTML email sent from localhost using PHP</p>';

    $mail->Subject = 'Email from Localhost';
    $mail->Body    = $bodyContent;
```

But it doesn't work. I found people on the internet changing some `php.ini` and `sendmail.ini` codes. Am I supposed to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You are using PHPMailer's SMTP client class, which is generally not affected by ini file settings.

It's not clear if this is all your code, but you don't have a call to the `send` method in what you have posted. That would certainly stop it from sending.

If it's not those things, I recommend following the troubleshooting guide and searching on here - just about everything to do with PHPMailer has been asked here before!